# Unable to create Oracle APEX Application ERROR ORA-20001

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create a library system (school work) using oracle 10g but i got stuck in creating the simple APEX report and form, the error message says:

> ORA-20001: Unable to create modules. ORA-20001: Create pages error.
>   ORA-20001: Unable to create form page. ORA-20001: Error page=8
>   item="P8_BRANCHID" id="" ORA-20001: Error page=8 item="P8_BRANCHID"
>   id="" has same name as existing application-level item. ORA-0000:
>   normal, successful completion
>
> Unable to create application.

This is my schema, in case I did something wrong:

```
create table publisher(
PublisherName varchar2(30) not null,
Address varchar2(30) not null,
Phone number(20),
constraint publisher_pk primary key (PublisherName)
);

create table book(
BookId number(4) not null,
Title varchar2(50) not null,
PublisherName varchar2(30) not null,
constraint book_pk primary key (BookId),
constraint book_fk foreign key (PublisherName)
references publisher (PublisherName)
);

create table bookauthors(
BookId number(4) not null,
AuthorName varchar2(30) not null,
constraint bookauthors_pk primary key (BookId,AuthorName),
constraint bookauthors_fk foreign key (BookId) references book (BookId)
);

create table librarybranch(
BranchId number(4) not null,
BranchName varchar2(30) not null,
Address varchar2(30) not null,
constraint librarybranch_pk primary key (BranchId)
);

create table borrower(
CardNo number(4) not null,
BName varchar2(30) not null, 
Address varchar2(30) not null,
Phone number(20) not null,
constraint borrower_pk primary key (CardNo)
);

create table bookcopies(
BookId number(4) not null,
BranchId number(4) not null,
No_Of_Copies number(4) not null,
constraint bookcopies_pk primary key (BookId,BranchId),
constraint bookcopies_fk foreign key (BookId) references book (BookId),
constraint bookcopies2_fk foreign key (BranchId) references librarybranch (BranchId)
);

create table bookloans(
BookId number(4) not null,
BranchId number(4) not null,
CardNo number(4) not null,
DateOut date,
DueDate date,
constraint bookloans_pk primary key (BookId,BranchId,CardNo),
constraint bookloans_fk foreign key (BookId) references book (BookId),
constraint bookloans2_fk foreign key (BranchId) references librarybranch (BranchId),
constraint bookloans3_fk foreign key (CardNo) references borrower (CardNo)
);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but the `bookloans` table needs some adjustments, I think. The FKs 1 and 2 should be combined into one: `constraint bookloans_fk foreign key (BookId, BranchId) references librarybranch (BookId, BranchId)`

Comment: You could also add a Check constraint that `DateOut < DueDate`.

Comment: And a way to enforce that the libray has not loaned 4 (or 100) copies of a book that only 3 copies exist. (that is harder than a simple change to the schema)

Comment: Not sure but I think this question would be improved (for future visitors) by deleting the schema, since it's not related to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your schema; this error ORA-20001 is a custom application error raised by the Apex application, not the database. I would take the message at face value: `...Error page=8 item="P8_BRANCHID" id="" has same name as existing application-level item`. It appears your page 8 has a page item named `P8_BRANCHID` but there may also be a similar item defined in application items. Go to your application items and see if you have one named the same.

Comment: How will i be able to go to application items?

Comment: @J4RG0N From in your Apex application, go to Shared Components, then to Application Items.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the page number you are trying to create already exists in the APEX Application. Change the page number and it should work